# Is it safe to manually remove packages that apt-get remove/autoremove left behind?

Tags: server, apt, software-installation, software-uninstall

Facts:
Yesterday I installed `openjdk-7-jre` in a Ubuntu Server 14.04, which installed over 100+ packages.
Later, I realized that I would only need to install `openjdk-7-headless`.
Then I uninstalled openjdk-7-jre with `apt-get remove` and also `apt-get autoremove`.
However, this process only removed a small subset of the whole `openjdk-7-jre` package and its dependencies.

Questions:
1 - Is it safe to manually remove each one of the dependencies packages listed by the entry in `/var/log/apt/history.log` regarding the initial installation of `openjdk-7-jre`?
2 - Why the `remove/autoremove` commands didn't remove the whole package (jre + dependencies), since I haven't done anything else between the initial installation and the later `remove/autoremove` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,  Ubuntu/Linux never let's you remove something that is important in boot systems,  unless you use GEdit

Comment: I can think of a number of commands one can run which would cause total system failure.

Comment: @Charles Could you be more specific as to how removing a list of packages can "cause total system failure"?

Comment: @Charles To be absolutely precise, could you be more specific as to how removing a **known** list of **dependency** packages can "cause total system failure"?

Comment: I'm unsure that removing a dependancy will do this, but that is not what was indictated by the answer you posted, indicating that Ubuntu would not allow the removal of anything important.

Comment: @Rogier, so you mean that I can safely manually remove all dependencies that were not automatically removed by apt-get autoremove? Then I wonder what have prevented apt-get autoremove from removing them...